# Issue with importing a group during active directory setup: "Bad request LDAP group could not be found based on search criteria..."

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

After setting up LDAP connection successfully, I'm attempting to import a group into my ICP so that users within our active directory can log into the ICP platform. On the Import Group screen, I've attempted to use many different variations of CN= OU= but I'm not sure what the fields should contain and keep getting the following error: "Bad request LDAP group could not be found based on search criteria. Please refine your search and try again."

Answer (score 0):

Which ICP release are you used? 2.1.0 or 2.1.0.1? You can run below command to check:

```
docker images | grep icp-inception
```

It should be a known issue for ICP 2.1.0, please upgrade ICP to 2.1.0.1 if you are using 2.1.0, thanks.